# Google Maps api not loading in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

We have a google maps page at:

http://roadreport.mdt.mt.gov/travinfomobile/

It works fine on all browsers, except it appear to not load the google maps api on ie7 or ie10 compatibility mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the down votes, regardless of the "official google support", this app loads fine in ie7 and is basically the same: http://roadreport.mdt.mt.gov/travinfomobiledev/MCS_BRIDGE/map.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps JavaScript API does not support IE7, or IE's compatibility view, and rightfully so. Internet Explorer 7 needs to finally die, now that its global market share has dropped below 1%.

> The Google Maps JavaScript API supports the following web browsers:
>
> Google Maps JavaScript API v3:
>
> For desktop:
>
> - **Internet Explorer 8–10 inclusive (Windows)**
> - The current and previous version of Firefox (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)
> - The current and previous version of Chrome (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)
> - The current and previous version of Safari (Mac OS X)
>     For Android:
> - Default browser on Android 2.3+ (which is Chrome on 4.1+)
>     For iOS:
> - Mobile Safari on the current and previous major version of iOS
> - Current version of Chrome for iOS
>
> **Internet Explorer's Compatibility View is not supported.**

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport

Comment: +1 for the "Internet Explorer 7 needs to finally die"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with IE on windows phone 8 release be blocking API.

You must use the domain "maps.google.co.uk" not "maps.googleapis.com"

Google Map API URL working: https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false

Also queries tend to be faster.